# Cant get Tizen app to work which is written in preact

Tags: javascript, web, tizen, preact

I have an app written in preact which I would like to test, but I am unable to get it working on the Tizen tv emulator.

After some research, I found a few instances of people creating apps for Tizen with react but never actually using preact.

Has anyone experience with getting preact apps to work on the Tizen platform?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in `preact` itself that might cause the app to not work on Tizen. In fact it should work much better then a `react` version. I've not only seen, but have written apps in React for Tizen (even legacy ones). The real reason of the failure might be that the app is not transpiled appropriately for the Tizen platform. You should be targeting at least ES2015. Also be sure to include pollyfills if you are using fancy data structures, like `Set` for example.

It would help if you could post the error that you receive in Tizen emulator. You can run the app in debug mode and actually see all suspicious output in the console of the detached WebKit devtools that debug mode auto-opens for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to get everything working in the end... My bad for not providing detailed info about the error. It originated from a corrupt config.xml whch caused a parsing error during the app installation. I also found out that I had to provide the entire ID defined in the config file in order to successfully launch, rather than the short one... otherwise this caused a NullPointerExeption. Keep in mind that I tried to avoid using Tizen Studio due to not liking it, but had to in the end, cause I'm not aware of a possibility to launch debug mode from the CLI.